# Font compression! RLE or Huffman or nothing?

Tags: c, embedded, compression

I am working on an embedded project (ARM7). In my application I have to store lots of Chinese characters which waste around 300k of my flash. The current font encoding is Unicode which comprises 22 bytes for every character because every glyph is 12*12 plus one line space on left and bottom side which makes it 169 pixel (22 bytes) (see the example). As an example, the Unicode for this Chinese character 
[image]

is as follows:
          /* unicode5939*/
      0x40, 0x44, 0x4c, 0x54, 0x64, 0xff, 0xff, 0x44,
      0x54, 0x4c, 0x44, 0x40, 0x0, 0x8, 0x11, 0x11,
      0x0, 0x8, 0x82, 0x20, 0x4, 0x0.

The current Unicode is like this: the upper 8 rows of the glyph are exactly equal to first 13 bytes of the Unicode (column based not row based, from right upper side). The rest 9 bytes represent the 5 bottom rows of the glyph (look at the right side from the left side, column by column put 0 and 1 in a byte until the byte gets full and so on).

If we do RLE compression on this Unicode (bitwise) the result needs more than 22 bytes to store the repetition number for every run (As far as I did it by hand). So I want to do another type of compression. Any clue?

Comment: From your requirements it looks like lz4 or some other lz* would be appropriate. There are many implementations for embedded world.

Comment: I don't see any relation between the character and the set of data. It's not a bitmap -- or is it? I'm assuming you are mis-using the term "Unicode", you need to look that up before using it in a sentence such as "font encoding is Unicode which comprises 22 bytes for every character".

Comment: Thanks for the comments! actually I have been given the characters images and also those codes (which is stated unicode in the file). It seems that it is automatically generated by something called XML2c conversion tool according to the file header. The image is 12*12 but it seems that one more space has been used on right-side and bottom of the character so the code is for 13*13 glyph.

Comment: Do you have enough RAM to decompress the whole font, or do you have to  extract individual glyphs from the compressed data held in the flash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Font compression could be handled even on per/glyph basis using e.g. arithmetic coding with say 4-bit neighborhood:

```
[ 4 ] [ 3 ] [ 2 ]
[ 1 ] ( x )
```

Each neighborhood of pixels p1,p2,p3,p4 codes the probability of x==0 vs x==1, which is updated after the bit 'x' is processed; Unlike Huffman coder, an arithmetic coder is able to compress symbols in smaller units than a single bit, the limit given by Shannon's information theory.

```
Context,    count               bits per symbol  
Zeros[ 0] = 45   Ones[ 0] = 4   19.987
Zeros[ 1] = 7    Ones[ 1] = 4   10.402
Zeros[ 2] = 6    Ones[ 2] = 0   0.000
Zeros[ 3] = 2    Ones[ 3] = 2   4.000
Zeros[ 4] = 6    Ones[ 4] = 5   10.934
Zeros[ 5] = 0    Ones[ 5] = 1   0.000
Zeros[ 6] = 2    Ones[ 6] = 0   0.000
Zeros[ 7] = 9    Ones[ 7] = 4   11.576
Zeros[ 8] = 5    Ones[ 8] = 13  15.343
Zeros[ 9] = 1    Ones[ 9] = 3   3.245
Zeros[10] = 4    Ones[10] = 0   0.000
Zeros[11] = 1    Ones[11] = 3   3.245
Zeros[12] = 2    Ones[12] = 2   4.000
Zeros[13] = 1    Ones[13] = 0   0.000
Zeros[14] = 1    Ones[14] = 5   3.900
Zeros[15] = 3    Ones[15] = 3   6.000
Total 92.634 bits = 12 bytes
vs. no context, 
Zeros = 95           Ones = 49      133.212 bits = 17 bytes
```

The obvious question is how to initialize the array:

1) use a fixed, i.e. static model of the frequencies
  2) use fully adaptive model, assuming 50:50 chance in the beginning
  3) use a set (2-256?) of fixed models, that best characterizes the glyph
  4) start with some model from a precalculated set and update

A complete model would require 32 bytes to encode values of 0..169, and thus can't be passed with a character unless very strongly (and cleverly) compressed.

**EDIT**
If a single (or very few global static tables are used), one can also enlarge the table to 5,6,7 -pixel neighborhoods, or embed information of pixel position to the table (this method fails to encode the condition 'x is at bottom line'):

```
[ B ] [ C ] [ D ],          where A,B,C,D = 00 for 'white'
[ A ]  (x)                                  11 for 'black'
                                            01/10 for pixel outside canvas 

or
[ 1 ] [ 3 ] [ 4 ] [ 5 ] [ 6 ]       + [ x is next to border? ]
[ 0 ] [ 2 ]  (x)
```

Further reading:
 - [Fax Compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fax#Compression) / [JBIG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JBIG)
 - [Arithmetic Coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding)

Answer (score 2):

You'll get an almost 20% improvement by not storing the blank lines with each glyph.

12x12 instead of 13x13  = 18 bytes instead of 22.

Answer (score 1):

*(not an actual answer, but I needed more space than a comment)*

Well, at least 13*13 would fit the 22 bytes (it's 169 bits, thus 21 1/8 bytes). When laid out as bytes, it looks like this:

```
01000000   01000    00010
01000100   01000    00010
01001100   00100    00100
01010100   00010    01000
01100100   00001    10000
11111111   00000    00000 Reordered by groups of five bits,
11111111   00000 <- 00000 <--------------------------+
01000100   00001    10000 flipped again             |
01010100   00010    01000                           |
01001100   00100    00100                           |
01000100   01000    00010                           |
01000000   01000    00010                           |
00000000   00000    00000                           |
00001000 -> 00010000 <- Bottom 9 bytes reversed: \  |
00010001 -> 10001000                             |  |
00010001 -> 10001000                             |  |
00000000 -> 00000000                             |  |
00001000 -> 00010000                             +--+
10000010 -> 01000001                             |
00100000 -> 00000100                             |
00000100 -> 00100000                             |
00000000 -> 0        (only one useful bit)       /
```

At least the top 13 bytes definitely look like the top 8 lines of the character (upside on the right). For the bottom 9 bytes, once reversed, they can be laid out by groups of 5 bits and look like the bottom part.

Or more readably, it's all encoded like this:
[image: Glyph storage diagram]

Now **to answer the actual question**, I'm sure trying to compress glyphs individually is a recipe for disaster. Can't compress all in one block either, because of the lack of room to store the uncompressed data. So, the compression needs to be done in blocks of X glyphs, with a caching system for decompressed blocks.

Comment: Thanks, the total number is around 900 glyphs. so totally it is somthing like 20K.

Comment: @user1469187: if the data compresses down to 16K and the decompression code itself is 3K long, would that be an improvement? In other words: you would trade (easy to parse) data for complicated code (plus run-time issues such as handling temporary decompression memory, and the overhead of decompressing itself). Also, 20K is not a lot--how big a chunk is it of what you have available?

Comment: @jongware thanks for the comment. actually the whole data is around 300K. My assignment is working on part of it (22K) to see if compression works ok or not. If the compression works perfect, then it will be done on the other data. The flash has around 300K space left. If we cannot compress the data, the flash would be somewhat full,

Comment: @user1469187: okay, that's a fair assessment -- compressing by at least 10% would be worth the effort. Can you explain how the byte values translate to the bitmap character? As Medinoc shows, this one doesn't seem to add up. Best is to provide an *actual* example. (Edit your post, please.)

Comment: @Jongware I edited the main post. by the way the example is actual ;)